# Mostrar mensaje en pantalla C++

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo en esto de c++. Tengo el siguiente código y el compilador me tira error:

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
cout << "Hola mundo!" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

qué me está faltando? Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola, agrega siempre (como texto) el error o errores que te muestra el compilador. Simplemente te falta indicar  el namespace de la biblioteca estándar: `std::cout << "Hola mundo!" << std::endl;`...

Comment: gracias, esta forma de hacerlo no la conocía

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola! Te está faltando incluir el namespace `std` para poder reconocer a `cout` y a `endl`. Simplemente agrega la siguiente línea de código luego de `#include<iostream>`:

```
using namespace std;
```

¡Espero haber sido de ayuda! Un saludo.

Comment: El abuso de la cláusula `using namespace std;` está considerado mala práctica. Sería conveniente añadir a la respuesta las buenas prácticas de uso de dicha cláusula.

Answer (score 0):

Intente con este , es el que viene por defecto en un IDE y compila bien.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Tengo que seguir practicando

Comment: El abuso de la cláusula `using namespace std;` está considerado mala práctica. Sería conveniente añadir a la respuesta las buenas prácticas de uso de dicha cláusula.